# Options from HTML select inside a Stack Overflow question or answer will be positioned fixed

Tags: bug, stack-snippets

As the title already tells: When someone is answering a question or creating a question with a fiddle inside and when this fiddle contains a HTML `<select>` element, the child `<option>` elements will be scrolling with the page when clicked on (allowing for the same effect as setting an element to a (CSS property) `position: fixed`).

An example of this bug could be found on a question on the [following page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5805059/how-do-i-make-a-placeholder-for-a-select-box).

In order to reproduce, hit the "Run code snippet" button followed by clicking on the `<select>` element. Start scrolling (with mouse cursor outside of the snippet) to see the bug happening.

Comment: Seems like something you should report to Chrome. The browser is supposed to close the menu when you scroll, but seems not to when the select menu is inside a frame. Firefox handles this correctly.

Comment: I seem to be unable to reproduce this "bug" on my local machine in a local file when running/rendering inside Chrome, would you be able to reproduce this outside of the Stack Exchange platform? This makes me doubt it is a browser related problem. @animuson I made use of a basic `<iframe>` element which would render a page containing a `<select>` element and enough height set on `<div>` elements in order to make scrolling possible. It is working just fine. Would this not mean it is something on Stack's side?

Comment: The code I used for trying to reproduce it locally: This [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kam9g6yz/) contains an `<iframe>` which should render the page containing a `<select>`:  [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ak2n8w3o/)

Comment: To close voters: the bug was *fixed*. As it's tagged as under review, I've flagged it to ask for a [tag:status-completed] tag now.

Comment: @SonictheBracketedHedgehog We did nothing to fix this. Internally, it was silently rejected because it was extremely minor and not clearly anything to do with our code. But we were able to further diagnose it as only occurring if you open the select menu, move your cursor *outside of the iframe* and then try to scroll. It's just Chrome not handling that case correctly.